# How to pronounce the ending -ig if it has another consonant after it?

Tags: pronunciation

Or more specifically, in the case of the small Austrian village "Obergnigl",
is it pronounce:
/obergnɪçl/  or /obergnɪgl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter. The 'i' remains long. Here, the consonant does not change the pronunciation of the syllables in front of it.

Comment: / obɐˈgniːgl / I think (just wanted to try out my new IPA tool)